# Android Application force closed when sending over 100 text messages

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a text message a certain amount of times how ever when i do anything over 100 it force closes the application. Any suggestions?

Ok so here is my updated code, having a few additional problems now -- the toast will NEVER disappear and if i enable my if statements for data validation it will not work (basically trying to prompt the user to enter information if it's null instead of just force closing the application)

Here is my updated code:

```
package net.learn2develop.SMS;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText PhNumber, Message, TxtCount;
Button btnSendSMS;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //create text box to enter phone number
    PhNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhNumber);

    //create text box to enter message
    Message=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Message);

    //create text box to see how many times the user wants to send message
    TxtCount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtCount);

    //create button to send text message
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    //create listener for button
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {               
        public void onClick(View v)
            {           
                //variable for count.
                int count = 1;
                //variable for text message
                String msg = Message.getText().toString();
                //variable for phone number
                String num = PhNumber.getText().toString();
                //variable for the amount of text messages to send.
                int max = Integer.parseInt(TxtCount.getText().toString());
                //variable to watch button and hide keyboard
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                //test to see if count has any value at all
                //if (TxtCount.getText().toString().equals(""))
                //{
                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter a number of times to nuke!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  return;
                //}
                //test to see if number has a value
                //else if (num.equals(""))
                //{
                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter a phone number to nuke!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  return;
                //}
                //test to see if there is a message
                //else if (msg.equals(""))
                //{
                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter a message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  return;
                //}             

                //if all fields have valid data -- send text message until count = max                      
                while (count <= max) {                  
                    sendSMS(num, msg);
                    count++;
                };
                //hide the keyboard
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(TxtCount.getWindowToken(), 0);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(PhNumber.getWindowToken(), 0);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Message.getWindowToken(), 0);
                //set phone number to ""
                PhNumber.setText("");
                //set message to ""
                Message.setText("");
                //set count to ""
                TxtCount.setText("");
                //refocus on phone number
                PhNumber.requestFocus();                    
            }           
    });        
}

//sends a sms message to another device
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //when the sms has been sent
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Nuked!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break; 
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Nuked!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not sent",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using an android device for mass texting.

Comment: Why are you sending 100 text messages in short succession?

Comment: Could you please post logs in LogCat ?

Comment: Simply for my own amusement, i have a coworker who never wakes up on time and this annoys him till he's awake and coming to work.

Comment: @Nguyendat -- i'm not exactly new to Java but when it errors out there is nothing in the LogCat window

Comment: just out of curiosity, how many different phone-numbers does this lazy co-worker have? ;) I mean, it must be a fair few since you need the phone number text field? :P

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try splitting up the messages, or sending them out on a timer instead of a loop, you could try something like this:

```
               Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   Thread.sleep(100);
                           // Send message
               }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should arrange for the service to send a broadcast when each message has been sent (or failed), and only then send out the next one. You are probably swamping the service, which is causing the force close.

Check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) on how to use a "sent intent".